# Why is there no latch in this circuit?

Tags: fpga, vhdl, xilinx, synthesis

So I have come across this code and when I synthesize it I was surprised that there is no latch.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity practising is
port(
    a,b,c: in std_logic;
    z: out std_logic
);
end practising;

architecture behavioural of practising is
signal y: std_logic;
begin

test: process(a, b, c)
begin
    y <= a nand b;
    z <= c or y;

end process;

end architecture behavioural;
```

I thought it will create a latch as I defined y as a signal so its value will change at the end of the process, therefore, the output Z will keep its value until the process is instantiated again, so there must be a latch to store the value of Z. However, when I synthesized the code there was no latch present.
[image]

Comment: without knowing what the purpose of the module is, why are we making assumptions on whether it should contain a latch or not? Especially, it's called "practising", which sounds a lot like it was a student practice result, and thus has a high likelihood of actually *not* being correct.

Comment: Why should be latch there? Isn't this schematic clearly implementing what is written? `signal` is a *wire*, and does not imply anything about being latched. It needs not to be "saved" over iterations as it is always assigned within the process.

Comment: As long as A,B and C aren't changing, why do you think Z would change?

Comment: You have designed combinational block; if you would put riding_edge into conditions then it would be the latch: https://www.nandland.com/vhdl/tutorials/tutorial-process-part2.html

Comment: @Anonymous: you can make a latch without using any edge conditions using an `if : if A then B <= C; end if;` You get registers (not latches) if you use `rising_edge`

Comment: When describing combinational ckts in VHDL, make sure that the sensitivity list contains all signals that appear at the "right side" of all expressions in your code. Cz they are all drivers. This is done to make sure that simulation and synthesised H/W behavior don't mismatch. H/W synthesied doesn't depend on the senstivity list(it is ignored), but only the behavioral code. :D

Answer (score 1):

Synthesis ignores sensitivity lists and assumes they are correctly and fully written.

Your code with all four signals in the sensitivity list does not describe a latch (since an update on y would force an update on z by rerunning the process), so your code does not describe a latch.

Most synthesis tools will generate a warning in a log somewhere that mentions it assumes as full sensitivity list.

Comment: Pedant mode - synthesis doesn't "assume [sensitivity lists] are correctly and fully written" - it does what you said first, and ignores them :)

Comment: However, a synthesis simulation mismatch warning comes I guess in Xilinx ISE